# Another rails upgrade dilemma

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-3-upgrade

soliciting advice about upgrading (or re-writing?) a legacy app. It's a single page webapp with lots of dynamically generated windows and forms, roughly comprised of

- 13,000 lines in .rb files
- 11,000 lines in .erb files
- 25,000 lines of javascript (not including large 3rd party libraries that bring this to nearer 60000 lines)

This acts as a UI for end users of our system, which also has a number of core business services (mostly written in Java, with a small amount of Node.js) and a fairly sizeable MySQL database (>200GB). Some of these services push AJAX to the client browser for real-time updates.

**Reasons for upgrade**

- It's ruby 1.8.7, rails 2.3.15. Most of the core code dates from 2009. This makes it both insecure and hard to maintain (think "predates the existence of gemfiles".)
- The app has been maintained by Java devs for most of its life, as most of the company's devs have been hired as Java devs to work on all the other services that perform business logic. It's probably safe to assume that this has lead to lots of hacks from people who didn't want to break anything, and certainly lots will not be done in a "rails way".
- The javascript is also a bit of a mess. It's got a knot of frameworks (the original Angular is used sporadically; jquery and prototype are both fighting over the $ symbol in different places.) There are files that are 7000 lines long.
- the css styling has been upgraded since 2009(!) but is starting to look a little tired. We'd like to implement a bootstrap theme that will look sharp without too much front-end skill, but right now the code that renders all of our pop-up windows, sidebars etc breaks badly if we try and add bootstrap.
- It would be nice to modernise our push servers, replacing them with websockets.

**Context**

There are 3 of us on the dev team- this is my first job, and I've only been here since January. Of the other two, one has only been here about 4 months longer than me, and it's his first dev job too. The other guy is the only one who has ever spoken to someone who spoke to someone from the original team.

Oh, and of course we have little or no test coverage.

**Options**

When I was hired (as a Java developer), I was told that we were looking to replace the website with one based on Spring MVC. This effort is partially underway, having been attacked in drips and drabs over a couple of years. Because different devs who never met have attacked it as if it's their own brand new project, the same problems are solved in different ways in different places. They've tried some flashy techniques such as custom annotations that I find hard to follow, but as far as I can tell don't fully work. The most senior of us estimates it would take our team a year's dedicated full-time work to finish it (which is not a realistic business proposition, based on how many requests for new features we get from customers).

I'm inclined to upgrade the website rather than spin out a new one. This is partly because I can see the sense in **that** [post](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2000/04/06/things-you-should-never-do-part-i/). Another reason is that we're all employed as jack-of-all trade full stack developers (doubling as DBAs, sysadmins, etc...). We've got no particular expertise in UI design, and the UI for our present interface, although dated, is pretty user-friendly; it feels like a blank canvas would throw that structure out, and play to our weaknesses. Upgrading ruby/rails would also make any features we add during the upgrade much easier to add to the new site.

Apparently some experienced ruby devs who are friends with my boss have advised him informally it'd be so much work to bring the website up to date that it would be comparable to a complete re-write, which was the motivation for the spring project. This would have the advantage of only having to think about Java + javascript, and not trying to hire people who know both Java and ruby well.

Conventional wisdom seems to be upgrade rails in stages. I'm not sure how well this would work for us, for 2 reasons. For one thing, there 3 major versions for us to upgrade, which might have significant changes between them. More importantly, the code needs some TLC anyway with refactoring and the creation of a test suite.

I'm inclined to follow the following strategy:

1. Invest some developer time in training, to get a sense of the relevant best practises and the "rails ways" of doing things, rather than the "good enough to hack" knowledge most of us have now.
2. fire up a new rails 5.1 project on ruby 2.4.0
3. Configure active record to use our old database
4. Copy across the javascript from the public folder of the existing project in to the relevant parts of the asset pipeline and save that headache for "phase 2".
5. Sort out a gemfile with updated versions of our dependencies (for example, mysql gem has been replaced by a mysql2 gem.) Installing [rubocop](http://rubocop.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) seems like a good idea at this point.
6. Copy files across from old to new project one at a time. Read the code, figure out what it's doing, write the relevant tests, fix where they break. Use the ruby API and rails upgrade guides to update the syntax. Refactor until rubocop is appeased.
7. Once we've reproduced the functionality of the existing site, write a new stackoverflow post on how to sort out the javascript ;)

This certainly sounds like a lot of work, but seems less likely to produce a buggy mess than trying to reproduce our existing functionality from scratch in a different language. So...

**Questions**

1. Does this strategy seem sensible? Is this a case where the re-write is really a better option? Is tackling the JS separately the best call, or is it better to restructure it as we're examining the calls to it from the views? Or should we *really* upgrade -> 3.0, 3.1, ... 5.0, 5.1?
2. We've altered the database manually, adding new tables, new fields and whatnot directly rather than using .`rails generate`. 'Rails magic' seems to make this work at present, but should we anticipate problems in step 3?
3. Is there any logical order in which to approach the migration of ruby? As there's major changes to the routing, which is the central entry point of the application, it seems sensible to start there, followed by authentication, then the main page, and then add functions one at a time.
4. Part of the problem is "not knowing what we don't know" about the rails way of doing things. Apart from the canonical Ruby/Rails tutorials (Hartl, Ruby Monk, Ruby Koans, Kehoe's rails book), is there any essential reading we should be aware of before trying to take on such a large job? I'm especially thinking about things that may not be immediately obvious, like proper use of helper functions, module structure, etc.
5. Any other advice, comments, prayers, ... welcome!

Comment: Wow, this is a tiny bit too broad for SO. You are gonna have to limit yourself to one question per post, and be more specific.

Comment: It sounds like you should be paying a consultant to answer these highly in-depth topics!!! Sorry, but I don't have time to give free advice on this level...

Comment: Whichever route you take, this project could *easily* take 6-12 months. And if done improperly by an inexperienced team, then you *could* easily end up with the same crappy old code base, copy+pasted into Rails 5 syntax without fixing the underlying issues. You need to take a **long hard look** at the existing code base and plan what the overall architecture/design is. This is far beyond the scope of a single SO post, but I'd be happy to advice on specific problematic areas.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks!  Do you think just question 1. would be a better fit on softwareengineering.stackexchange? There seems to be more discussion of questions around re-writing in general there, although this is also a very ruby/rails-specific issue (as e.g. Java/Spring seems to have much stronger backwards compatibility...)